# Rounding to nearest multiple of pixel resolution using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, pixel, round-function

ArcPy can return the pixel resolution:

```
arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management(rasterfile, "CELLSIZEX", "").getOutput(0))
```

Let's say this returns "3.2808"

I wish to be able to take a given input, say "10" for example, and return the nearest multiple of the pixel resolution

```
n = 3.2808
MagicRoundingFunction(n, 10)
>>> 9.8424
```

**Is there a built in function to accomplish this or must a custom function be developed?**

If one exists, I would rather save time using something built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any function that accomplish that implemented within `arcpy`. However, it is a rather simple function and it could look something like:

```py
import math


def magic_rounding_function(res, n):
    """
    :param res: pixel resolution
    :param n:   arbitrary number
    :return:    nearest multiple of the pixel resolution to n
    """
    return math.floor(n / res) * res
```

You can omit the `import math` statement and just do a floor division (*i.e.* `n // res`) as well.

Calling the function with your values:

```py
res = 3.2808
n = 10
magic_rounding_function(res, n)  # 9.842400000000001
```

Comment: The floor division operator has been around since Python 2.2, fyi

Comment: @mikewatt Great, will edit the answer.